# Execute function from Methods Scope in jquery datatable Options -- Vue2

Tags: vuejs2, datatables, nuxt.js

How can I get **setOrders function** which defined in  **methods** object, in **jquery datatables** scope which is defined on **data** object in vue component. I actually want to run function which is in methods obj from **v-on:click='setOrders(${order.statusid})'** which is in data -> dtOptionsObj -> createdRow() & createdRow is jquery datatable function.

```
data: () => ({
        order: [],
        showBtnOnTable: true,
        dtOptionsObj: {
            responsive: "responsiveModal",
            createdRow: function(row, order, dataIndex) {
                console.log('this is tihssss',this);
                $(`td:eq(1)`, row).html(
                    `<button class="sc-button" onclick='alert(${JSON.stringify(
                        order.apialerterid
                    )})'>${order.apialerterid}</button>`
                );
                // function setOrders(order) {
                //  console.log('this is event....', order)
                // }
                var ref = "";
                if (order.statusid == 0) {
                    ref = `<span class="uk-badge md-bg-green-500">Stopped/Refunded</span>`;
                } else if (order.statusid == 3) {
                    ref = `<button>Accept Chargeback</button>`;
                } else if (order.statusid == 4) {
                    ref = `<button>Not Found</button>`;
                } else if (order.statusid == 8) {
                    ref = `<span class="uk-badge md-bg-blue-600">Other</span>`;
                } else if (order.statusid == 12) {
                    ref = `<span class="uk-badge md-bg-orange-600">Previously Cancelled</span>`;
                } else if (order.statusid == 13) {
                    ref = `<span  class="uk-badge md-bg-danger-600">Too Late</span>`;
                } else {
                    ref = `<button class="sc-fab sc-fab-small sc-fab-danger" type="button" v-on:click='setOrders(${order.statusid})' data-uk-toggle="target: #modal-overflow">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-briefcase-plus"></i>
                                </button>
                                `;
                }
                $(`td:eq(${Object.keys(order).length - 1})`, row).html(ref);
            },
            columnDefs: [
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
                { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 },
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    visible: true,
                    searchable: false,
                    orderable: false
                }
            ]
        },
    }
```

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions("entities", ["fetchAlerts"]),
   setOrders: function(data) {
   console.log("this is ordersss",data);
  this.order = order;
},
```

In short: I want **setOrders** function to run on **createdRow** which is in **dtOptionsObj**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this wrapper component https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net which allow you to define `data-action` to handle click.  The parameters are `data, row, tr, target`, and since `data` would be order, you could use `data.statusid` in your event handler.

Or you can go native and try the `b-table` component of `bootstrap-vue` with this `items-provider` - https://github.com/niiknow/bvtnet-items-provider